# Debian - sources.list for "testing" - what to change?

Tags: debian

I want to use testing-distribution (currently thats "wheezy" instead of the stable "squeeze") of Debian, and am about to adjust my /etc/apt/sources.list file.

I know that I have to replace squeeze by wheezy for the main entry.

But do I have to do this for security (squeeze/updates) and updates (squeeze-updates) too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, same logical structure for stable/testing.

If you want to stay on "testing" whenever a testing becomes stable and a new testing is given a name, you can use "testing" as a release name as well.

Something like :

```
deb ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib  non-free
```

What I usually do is the following:
1) on a stable productive system, I use the release name, example "squeeze"
2) on a testing system, I use the "testing" name like my example above.

This way,
1) your productive systems are not upgraded without you knowing what you're doing (changing the release name in sources.list when you're ready to upgrade)
2) your testing environments remains "testing" forever, whatever the release management cycle

I hope it helps,

Regards,

Jacques

Answer (score 3):

Well. http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/ suggests to use wheezy (or testing) at all places.